# Django reverse with keyword arguments not found

Tags: python, django, reverse

The `Reverse for 'signup' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'test': '123234'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['accounts/signup$']` error messages seem to apply to many different situations, so although there are a lot of stack overflow questions for this error message, I don't seem to be able to find the answer to my question.

I have the following code in my `view.py` file:

```
def signup(request, test=0):   
    context = {}
    return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html', context)

def signup_request(request):
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('accounts:signup', kwargs={'test': '123234'}))
```

In my `urls.py` file I have:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'^signup$', views.signup, name='signup',),
                      )
```

When `signup_request` gets called, I get the error

```
Reverse for 'signup' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'test': '123234'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['accounts/signup$']
```

**However**

If I change the pattern in urls.py to

```
(1) url(r'^signup/(?P<test>\d*)$', views.signup, name='signup',)
```

it works.

Additionally, if I change the pattern in urls.py to

```
(2) url(r'^signup', views.signup, {'test':'123234'}, name='signup',)
```

it works.

But if I change the pattern in urls.py to

```
(3) url(r'^signup', views.signup, {'test':'123'}, name='signup',)
```

it doesn't work.

**I'd like to figure out how to do the following**

Call `HttpResponseRedirect` and have it call the `signup` method with a `test` argument. I do not want to have the test argument need to be part of the url (as in `(1)`), and I want to be able to change the values (so solution `(2)` won't work as `(3)` demonstrates).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Where have you declared the namespace in the url patterns?

Comment: What you're trying to do doesn't make sense in terms of url patterns a nd url reversing. suggest you append `test` as a querystring arg and retrieve it in the view via `request.GET` instead of a view arg

Comment: @karthikr yes, I have declared the namespace.

Comment: @Anentropic I'll take a look at that. I think that would resolve some of my issues. I was hoping to keep the parameters internal to the server-side logic, but if that's not feasible, then the `request.GET` sounds like it might be the way to go.

Comment: My current work around is to use @Anentropic's suggestion. I now have `HttpResponseRedirect("%s?test=123234" % reverse('accounts:signup'))`, have changed the method signature of `signup` to just take in `request`, and am checking the `request.GET` dictionary for `test`. If there's another way to do this with `kwargs`, that would be great, but I'm satisfied with this. Thanks, @Anentropic!

Comment: another possibility would be to do without the http redirect and just `return signup(request, '123234')` from `signup_request` (and still have `test` kwarg in the view signature) but then the browser url wouldn't change